# error: 'AcceptCallback' undeclared

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking

I'm trying to create a TCP server for iPhone.
I am following an example Journal of the iPhone to help "SimpleNetworkStream".
At compile time I get an error "error: 'AcceptCallback' undeclared (first use in this function).
Could someone help me understand why all of this.
The statement seems identical to that made by the example Journal.
Thanks

```
self.listeningSocket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(
              NULL,
              fd,
              kCFSocketAcceptCallBack,
              AcceptCallback,
              &context
              );



    static void AcceptCallback(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)

    {
    //code
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a forward declaration.

```
static void AcceptCallback(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info);
...
self.listeningSocket = CFSocketCreateWithNative( ... );
...
static void AcceptCallback(...) {
  ...
```

Or just put the whole definition of `AcceptCallback` before that assignment.